# Derivative Clifford algebra

Tags: derivatives, vectors, clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

How would I take the derivative of $S=e_1x$?

Let me investigate two paths to find the derivative:

1. Taking the derivative directly:

$$
dS=e_1dx
$$

2. Squaring to eliminate the basis, then taking the derivative. First, we note that $S=e_1 x\implies S/x=e_1$.

$$
S^2=(e_1 x)^2\\
S^2=x^2\\
\frac{d(S^2)}{dx}=\frac{d(x^2)}{dx}\\
2SdS=2xdx\\
\frac{dS}{dx}=\frac{x}{S}=(e_1)^{-1}\\
dS=(e_1)^{-1}dx
$$

In one case I obtain $dS=e_1dx$ and in the other, I obtain $dS=(e_1)^{-1}dx$. Does $(e_1)^{-1}=e_1$, or did I make a mistake?

Comment: What is $e_1$? What is $S$ and $x$???

Comment: $e_1$ is a generator of the Clifford algebra, S and x and just variables in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $e_1^2 = 1$, $e_1^{-1} = e_1$, the end results of both methods are equivalent.